# Is the case big enough?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, case

Another first build question. Will this case [CoolerMaster RC-942-KKN1](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6269869&Sku=C283-2080#) fit this motherboard [Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD5](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=667674&csid=_61_)

Comment: If it fits plain ATX, its big enough

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the case and motherboard are both ATX form factor and are compatible. In fact you can put smaller motherboards into the ATX case, just not the other way around. An ATX motherboard will not fit a micro ATX case for example.

Also, here is a sample of size and mounting screw layout of a few common sizes.

[image: Motherboard size and mounting holes]